# Weblogic. Cross domain over the same web application

Tags: java, spring, cross-domain, weblogic

I'm trying to configure our weblogic to accept cross domain.

I have the following problem:

I have two domains (www.a.com and www.a.net) and both domains are calling the same weblogic server.

When a user access to our web for www.a.com weblogic assigns a JSESSIONID. If the same user change to www.a.net weblogic creates a new session with a new JSESSIONID. Then, if the user is logged in www.a.net, he appears at the other domain as not logged.

I have Weblogic 11gR1 and spring security.

How can I configure weblogic to share session between different domains?

Thank you in advance.

Gus.

Comment: Sharing sessions and cross domain are 2 separate things.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve single-sign-on, or are you trying to share more state?

Comment: Also have you read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/secmanage/domain.html

Comment: I want to share session when a user access to the web with to different domains. www.a.com and www.a.net.